# Deserialize JSON to CSLA object list

Tags: c#, json, csla

I am not able to convert JSON to object format using CSLA.

**Here is my JSON:**

```
[
  {\"SupplyChainNodeId\":11046,
  \"PhoneNumber\":\"7704428881\",
  \"BranchNumber\":\"172\",
  \"BranchNameRaw\":\"\",
  \"BranchName\":\"AlpharettaGA #172\",
  \"Distance\":0.0,
  \"Street\":\"5610 Mcginnis Ferry Rd Bldg1\",
  \"Street2\":\"\",
  \"City\":\"Alpharetta\",
  \"StateCode\":\"GA\",
  \"PostalCode\":\"30005-3925\",
  \"Latitude\":\"34.0888920000000000\",
  \"Longitude\":\"-84.1972940000000000\",
  \"Description\":\"\",\"DisplayName\":\"172 - \",
  \"DivisionID\":\"\",
  \"AddressID":\"05815842-9fb1-45f2-86c4-5751b49413b9\",
  \"IsBusy\":false,
  \"IsSelfBusy\":false}
]
```

**Class format: **

```
[Serializable]
    public class BranchInfos : ReadOnlyListBase<BranchInfos, BranchInfo>
    {
}

public static Object PopulateDto(Object dto, string json)
{
    //Get the type of the target dto
    Type type = Type.GetType(dto.GetType().FullName);

    //convert to array if single row of data - this streamlines the deserialization process
    if (!json.StartsWith("["))
    {
        json = "[" + json + "]";
    }

    //Create settings so that not everyfield in dto is required
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;

    //Use the type pulled from dto and the json to populate the dto
    Object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type, settings);

    //The returned dto can now be casted to the correct dto type
    return (jsonObject);
}
```

Json convert to object format using these line of code:-

```
  List<BranchInfos> branchInfos = new List<BranchInfos>();
  branchInfos = (List<BranchInfos>)PopulateDto(branchInfos, json);
```

The exception when trying to convert the JSON to object format is:

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'BusinessLayer.Branch.BranchInfos' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath '[0].SupplyChainNodeId', line 1, position 22."}

Comment: `BranchInfos` is already a collection so `List<BranchInfos>` would map to a jagged 2d array in JSON.  Your JSON array is only 1d.

Comment: Can you please update the correct json